# Image Quality of Images Shared via Messages MMS

Tags: messages, photos

On iOS 8 on an iPhone 6, if I go to the Photos app, select one photo, and share via Messages, it will transfer at excellent quality.  However, if I select 20 photos and share via Messages, it transfers at noticeably poor quality.

Why is this?  Is there a way to fix this besides tediously sending one at a time?

Note: This is with iMessage disabled, images are being sent via MMS.

Comment: a single transfer is maxed at 3 Meg. A single pic at 3 Meg looks great. 20 pics in 3 Meg /20 = 150 k each

Comment: Is there a way to batch transfer and still have them send one at a time, or am I better off using something like Dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the size of the SMS package is controlled by the network provider but it is on average 3 Meg per message.

So a single photo will look sharp. How ever if you try to send multiple photos they have to fit in the 3 Meg bucket, and will be reduced in size.

You best option is to use Dropbox or Google drive, Photobucket ect.... if you want to send larger then 3 Meg files.

Basically select all photos and just upload to one of the services and then share (send link) to the other party.